# Weblogic Server 12.2.1.1.0 to Upgrade 12.2.1.3.0

Tags: web

We are currently using with Weblogic server 12.2.1.1.0 and now its outdated and Security issue because of that we are planning to upgrade weblogic 12.2.1.3.
 Anyone please give me steps to upgrade new version of weblogic 12.2.1.3.0